# socketio security issue and differences of socketio and long polling

Tags: node.js, socket.io

What are the security issues for the socket io in nodejs

Which one is better for real time updation using node js. Either socket io or long polling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Socket.io is a websocket. If you deploy your code in a shared hosting environment or if you are going via a firewall the websocket protocol might not work.

You can configure socket.io to default to a long-polling strategy in that case (which uses XHR requests). You will send your data normally to the websocket API, and it will decide which strategy to use. Long-polling is more cpu-consuming and it uses 2 sockets as it stablishes a 2 ways communication with the server.

Comment: Thank u for your valuable solution.

Comment: Can you give any example please.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend you to go through [this tutorial](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/).